# Некорректное имя при commit'ах на GitHub через Pycharm

Tags: git, github, pycharm

Поставил себе Git в PyCharm.

Создал новый аккаунт на GitHub, удалил локальные папки с репозиториями предыдущими. Те папки, которые .git на компе. Я даже удалил уже аккаунт старый на GitHub.

Но каждый раз, когда я делаю коммиты, в журнале PyCharm высвечивается старое имя.

[image: история фиксаций в Git]

Я уже заходил в настройки Control Versions в PyCharm, удалял там всё и добавлял заново. Добавил новый аккаунт там же в настройках GitHub, но старое имя всё равно каждый раз появляется.

Объясните, пожалуйста, как от этого избавиться?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Инструменты-Git-Хранилище-учётных-данных

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin
Я так понимаю, что надо что-то сделать пр помощи git-credential-erase, только я не совсем понимаю как и что. Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, объяснить? 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Обратите внимание, есть такой сайт [GitHub](https://github.com/), а есть такая программа [Git](https://git-scm.com/). Это разные вещи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В комментарии указали правильный сайт, только немного не ту статью.
Сайт кстати классный, спасибо за ссылку!

Вам нужна, на сколько я понял, статья [1.6 Введение - Первоначальная настройка Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git)
И конкретно:

> **Имя пользователя**
>
> Первое, что вам следует сделать после установки Git — указать ваше имя
> и адрес электронной почты. Это важно, потому что каждый коммит в Git
> содержит эту информацию, и она включена в коммиты, передаваемые вами,
> и не может быть далее изменена:
>
> ```
> $ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
> $ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
> ```
>
> Опять же, если указана опция `--global`, то эти настройки достаточно
> сделать только один раз, поскольку в этом случае Git будет
> использовать эти данные для всего, что вы делаете в этой системе. Если
> для каких-то отдельных проектов вы хотите указать другое имя или
> электронную почту, можно выполнить эту же команду без параметра
> `--global` в каталоге с нужным проектом.
>
> Многие GUI-инструменты предлагают сделать это при первом запуске.

По идее, это должно быть оно.